# Why can walls be any material but Schach has to be natural in a sukkah

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, sukkah, sukkot, masechet-sukkah

The Halacha is that Schach has to be made of natural material detached from the ground, my question is why Is that the case when a sukkah’s walls could be made of any material (so long as it doesn’t sway too much in the wind)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The walls and the s'chach have different functions.  The walls are there as a mechitzah - a barrier to ensure privacy and give a sense that you are inside a home.  The Gemarah in Sukkah discusses details such as a minimum height off the ground that a wall has to be, if it is suspended from poles/above, and one of the considerations is that animals can't be wandering into the Sukkah.

The s'chah is there to provide a measure of shade to ensure that it is comfortable.  The halacha is that there must be more shade than light.  However, the other stipulations ensure that the material that we use for s'chach doesn't protect us to the same degree as the roof of a house would, perhaps to remind us that when we look up, it is actually Hashem who is protecting us always, not the roof.

Comment: Citing sources for your claims would improve your answer post's quality.